# Importing data from files designated in an InputString dialog box

Tags: iterators, free-form-input

I want to use a loop to input several strings which will be used to import a file.  The number of strings to be imported will vary, so the loop should recognize the number of strings and stop after say an empty input.  Each iteration will contain a command of the kind:

```
Import[NotebookDirectory[] <>  StringJoin["start_", InputString[], ".dat"], HeaderLines -> 2]
```

which would import a file called start_XYX.dat from the notebook directory if the string XYX was entered.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `i = 0; While[ (str = InputString[]) != "", c[i++] = Import[...]]`?

Comment: Great, thanks!!!

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. It does not exhibit a trivial mistake nor will a useful answer be easily found in the documentation. This question brings up some serious issues concerning how to work with `InputString` and `Import` and how to defend against bad input from a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on pretty much the same idea as was presented by belisarius in his comment, but is more robust.

First I create two test files

**`start_test_1.dat`**

```
Header 1
Header 2
a b c d
```

**`start_test_2.dat`**

```
Header 1
Header 2
q w e r t y
1 2 3 4
```

on my desktop. I then set a path variable (you will, of course, need to set this to the path you want).

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop"}];
```

Given these preliminaries, the code for importing is

```
Clear[data];
n = 0;
While[(name = InputString[]) =!= $Canceled,
  data[++n] = 
    Quiet @ Import[FileNameJoin[{path, "start_" <> name <> ".dat"}], HeaderLines -> 2];
  If[data[n] =!= $Failed,
    Print[Row[{name, " imported"}]],
    data[n] =.; --n; Print[$Failed]]]
```

To test the code, I ran it and entered `start_test_1.dat` followed by Return into the 1st input dialog,`start_test_2.dat` followed by Return into the 2nd, and hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> when the 3rd appeared. The results were

> test_1 imported
>
> test_2 imported

```
Definition[data]
```

> ```
> data[1] = {{a, b, c, d}}
> data[2] = {{q, w, e, r, t, y}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
> ```

Note that to end the while-loop, you hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> or click on the dialog's **Cancel** button. You do not end it by entering an empty string. Note also that you get feedback about the import, and if if fails, the bad import is cleared and the file counter is decremented, so that the import can proceed without gaps.